# can't reset the location hash on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm trying to have the `window.location.hash` set to `null` or `""` each time a submit button is pressed, and then have the hash set to `#bottom`. Basically what I want is the hash to always = `#bottom` when they press a certain submit button. This is what I have right now.

```
       window.setTimeout(function() {

                           if (window.location.hash) {
                               window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
                           } else {
                               window.location.href += "#bottom";
                           }

                           location.reload();
                       }, 1000)
```

However the hash is always just staying the same each time the button is pressed. For example, if the hash is `mysite#reply` and I submit, it stays `mysite#reply`. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set it to the value that is returned by the `.replace()`.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        window.location.href = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    } else {
        window.location.href += "#bottom";
    }
    location.reload();
}, 1000)
```

Comment: the perfect usecase of the famous OR operator: window.location.href += window.location.hash||"#bottom";